# Execute a bundler task within a Guard callback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler, guard

I have a ruby on rails project that works with APIs from other projects. For development and testing I need to have these other 3 projects running, so I'm trying to get these up and running when I start guard.

There are shell scripts that start the services, so I used guard callbacks to run them, but some of the commands within the shell scripts don't work. For instance running another rails server doesn't work. It probably fails since the bundle environment is different, and the command would be calling bundle within bundle (guard is executed with bundle).

Is there another way of getting guard to start services, or is there a way to execute bundle within bundle?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, if this would help, but you may try to start guard without `bundle exec`

Answer (score 0):

When you execute the shell scripts from the Guard callbacks, you need to wrap the calls in `Bundler.with_clean_env`.

For example:

```
Bundler.with_clean_env { system("./start_other_app.sh") }
```

This clears out the environment variables Bundler uses internally so that you can run the other app in a new Bundler context.

See http://bundler.io/v1.3/man/bundle-exec.1.html#Shelling-out for more details.